# Deployment problems of asp.net 3.5 in iis 5.1

Tags: iis, .net-3.5, deployment

i have microsoft.net 3.5 application and have IIS5.1,,for deploying website 
do i need to do any thing aother than this

1.In IIS i created virtual directory named SPA and i browsed in to the location 
where my project is lacated and i added entire project file there( **Do i need to add
only bin file and login page or i need to add all pages???)**

2.In asp.net folder i selected tab version 2.0,,

3.when i browsed i can see all pages when i click login.aspx i am getting

this error

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): User does not have permission to perform this action.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +821651
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +186
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1932
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +172
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +381
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +181
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +173
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +133
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +30
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +424
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +494
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +82
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +105
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +111
   ChatTool.LoginForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Chat tool_Ameya\ProjectCode\Unisys Project Testing\Unisys Project\Login.aspx.cs:25
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +33
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +47
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1436
```

Comment: It seems like there's a problem with your connection string, rather than anything else. How do you connect with your database? (and PLEASE do not post username and password publicly...)

Comment: its an mdf file there app data

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\leaf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues of trying to use SQLExpress for deployed web applications.

Here's a link for working with SQL Server Express and ASP.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx